# Great Expectations Row Based Dimensions

Tags: dbt, great-expectations

I have data like this:

```
[   {
        "name": "Apple",
        "price": 1,
        "type": "Food"
    },
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "price": 0.90,
        "type": "Food"
    },
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "price": 1000,
        "type": "Computer"
    },
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "price": 900,
        "type": "Computer"
    }
]
```

Using the Great Expectations automatic profile, a valid range for `price` would be `0.90` to `1,000`. Is it possible to have it slice on the `type` dimension, so food would be `0.90` to `1` and computer would be `900` to `1000`? Or would I need to transform the data first using dbt? I know the column that will create the dimension, but I don't know the particular values.

Also, same question on differences between rows. Like if they had a timestamp, instead of `900` to `1000`, it validates -100 for the change in value.

Comment: How many types do you have that you'd need to group by? 2,10,100?

Comment: You've tagged dbt; are you using Great Expectations in Python, or the dbt port, https://github.com/calogica/dbt-expectations?

Comment: @tconbeer ge in python. dbt is part of the DAG

Comment: @sgdata I don't know. It comes from a feed that I poll periodically, and I'm looking for drastic changes. Perhaps it would be best to do some more transforming, and create a table of percentage change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this approach to first load the data in a pandas data frame:

https://discuss.greatexpectations.io/t/how-can-i-use-the-return-format-unexpected-index-list-to-select-row-from-a-pandasdataset/70/2